# sql server data to json using php

Tags: php, sql, json, sql-server, sqlsrv

My json code doesn't display anything, I have already tried many codes but nothing has helped.

```
include('connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT *  FROM items";  
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);

if( $stmt === false)
{
   echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";  
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  //this loop is working
{    
  echo $row['item_id'].", ".$row['item_name'].", ".$row['Barcode']."<br>"; 
}

$json = array();
do {
   while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $json[] = $row;
   }
} while ( sqlsrv_next_result($stmt) );

echo json_encode($json);  //empty?!
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
```

Comment: Move the `$json = array();` to before the first while loop.

Comment: You reset array every iteration.

Comment: @aynber having formatted the code better I don't think that's the issue

Comment: @OscarZarrus having formatted the code better I don't think that's the issue

Comment: @ADyson Good catch. Formatting makes things so much easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous likely issues with this:

1) Have you checked your query actually returns rows?

2) You're looping your data twice (two `while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array...` loops) which is not useful or efficient.

3) `the do...while ( sqlsrv_next_result($stmt) );` clause should be unnecessary as well, as fetch_array will know when it's got to the end of the data, and you've only got one resultset, so you don't need to move between them

4) you're echoing raw data as well as JSON, so if you make an ajax call to this script it'll fail because the response will partly contain non-JSON data

I think this will be sufficient to get you some sensible data:

```
include('connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT *  FROM items";  
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);

if( $stmt === false)
{
   echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";  
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}

$json = array();

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{    
     $json[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Right, I was about to answer the same thing. There's  a strange nested loop and array resets each statement +1

Comment: my query is working, I tried your code but it doesn't show anything too.

Comment: json is still empty

Comment: @EnasAK just for testing then, after the end of the loop, write `var_dump($json);` Does it show some results in your output? If it does, then you definitely have some data. In that the only logical possibility is that the json_encode operation failed. You can easily test this because you can check whether it returns false and see what the error was: write `$encodedJSON = json_encode($json); if ($encodedJSON === false) echo json_last_error_msg(); else echo $encodedJSON;`. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php (and `json_last_error()` will get you the error ID)

Comment: I tried var_dump($json) , it display array (size=0) empty @ADyson

Comment: this is an Enigma. Can you var_dump the $row variable each interation? what are the results? We must call an exorcist. If $row is an array and echo $row['item_id'] prints something, the $json var must be populated.

Comment: @EnasAK ok so we need to trace it back a little further. Really you should learn how to do your own debugging, but here's another test to carry out: _inside_ the while loop, write `var_dump($row);` and see if that echoes anything. You should get one echo per row. How many rows are you expecting from your results? _Before_ the while loop you can also write `echo "Number of rows returned: ".sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);` to check how many rows the original query returned.

Comment: @EnasAK if you still don't get any results from that, well...then your query is returning nothing. So you should re-check the data in your database, and also that your application is definitely connecting to the database you expect.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you so much for your help, I finally got an error there were some non-utf8 char, I solve this and my code is working now ^^

Comment: @ADyson sir I have a question, I have an image stored as VARBINARY on SQL server, How could I convert it to JSON? I am using the same code above.

Comment: @EnasAK you wouldn't convert an image to JSON per se. JSON is just a way to define a data structure, it can't directly represent an individual data item such as an image. If you want to return JSON as a response then you'd need to convert the image to base64, which is a text-based scheme for encoding image data. i.e. it becomes a string. Then you could set that string as the value of a property in a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

If **THIS** works:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  //this loop is working
{    
  echo $row['item_id'].", ".$row['item_name'].", ".$row['Barcode']."<br>"; 
}
```

the rest must work too.

As **ADyson** says:

```
if( $stmt === false)
{
   echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";  
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}

$json = array();

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{    
     $json[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

for double check add your echo in this code, like this:

```
if( $stmt === false)
{
   echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";  
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}

$json = array();

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{    
     echo $row['item_id'].", ".$row['item_name'].", ".$row['Barcode']."<br>";
     $json[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

If this code works, **accept the ADyson answer**

Answer (score 0):

here is a way to solve the issue .Hoping your query is well written.

```
$dataFinal= array();//final variable that will contain total array for json   
for($k=0;$k<count(variable_that_contents_the_resutl_array_query);$k++){

$ligne = array("item_id"=> $row['item_id'],
"item_name"=>$row['item_name'],"Barcode"=> $row['Barcode']); 
array_push($dataFinal, $ligne);//add line in array datafinal         

     }//end for loop
    $result = array($dataFinal);
    $response = new Response(json_encode($dataFinal));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
```